# Gnuplot Draw vertical from a file

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file VERTICAL.txt with the following structure :

```
201
269
614
669
705
```

with a script traffic.gp :

```
set terminal jpeg size 1024,768
set title "traffic path 0" 
set xlabel "Simulation duration"
set ylabel "Link load (%)"
set grid
set xtics 0,50,1100 
set ytics 0.0,10.0,100.0 
set key below center
plot [0:1100] [0.0:100.0] 'traffic_path0.txt' with lines title "path 0"
```

i want to use VERTICAL.txt in traffic.gp to see the corresponding line.

I tried to add:

```
set parametrics
set trange [0:100]
plot VERTICAL.txt , t
```

but the following error occurs :`"scripts/traffic.gp", line 11: parametric function not fully specified`

How can i managed to do that ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a somewhat dirty trick that only works if you're not autoscaling the y axis:

```
YMIN=0
YMAX=100.0
set yrange [YMIN:YMAX]
plot 'test.dat' u 1:2 w lines, \
     'VERTICAL.txt' u 1:(YMAX) w impulses ls 2, \
     'VERTICAL.txt' u 1:(YMIN) w impulses ls 2
```

(the YMIN part is actually unnecessary if YMIN is 0).

Another dirty hack you can play is with arrows and system commands:

```
set for [a in system("tr '\n' ' '<VERTICAL.txt")] arrow from first a,graph 0 to first a,graph 1 nohead
```

Comment: I managed to get what i want with your first "dirty" trick. I added the Ymin,max,range and the last two lines to my plot command in  traffic.gp. thanks a lot.

Comment: could you post the final script?